# How to create a list with frequency from an existing list

Tags: java, list

I just started working on a project, its purpose is to be a tool for my statistics class, I'm currently working on a console based so once I'm done with it I can move on and use UI. But I'm stuck in this problem, I want to create a new list based on my existing list.

```
public class Main {

    class ModifiedSample {
        double item;
        int frequency;

        ModifiedSample(Double item, int frequency) {
            this.item = item;
            this.frequency = frequency;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Double> sampleList = new LinkedList<Double>();
        LinkedList<ModifiedSample> modifiedSampleList = new LinkedList<ModifiedSample>();

    }
    
}
```

This is my simplified version of the class, I do have scanners and all that jazz.

If my sampleList = {2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6},
how can I make a modifiedSampleList = {sample1, sample2, sample3, sample4, sample5}
so that if create a method like:

```
static void printSampleSpace(LinkedList<ModifiedSample> modifiedSampleList) {
    for(ModifiedSample ms : modifiedSampleList) {
        System.out.println("item: " + ms.item);
        System.out.println("frequency: " + ms.frequency);
    }
}
```

I can get

```
item: 2                                                                          
frequency: 2                                                                     
item: 3                                                                   
frequency: 1                                                                          
item: 4                                                                               
frequency: 1                                                                          
item: 5                                                                       
frequency: 4                                                                          
item: 6                                                                               
frequency: 1
```

So I'm stuck in finding a solution for this problem.

Comment: you probably would be better off with a `Map` where the key is the value in the original list and the value is it's frequency. Then you can loop over the `Map.entrySet()` and print each key and value from there.

Comment: Oh yeah, I guess a map is better than a class whose the function is just the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using a list to represent the result sounds a bit strange to be. The textbook solution would be to create a frequency map, where the key is the sample and the value is its frequency:

```java
LinkedList<Double> sampleList = new LinkedList<Double>();
Map<Double, Long> frequencies = 
    sampleList.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting());
```

Comment: It worked like a charm, I don't understand all the method calls but I'll just read the documentation, thank you very much!